# Json parsing error using Java

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java, and want to parse the JSON response below. I can get to `ID` but not able to get to `startDate`.. Need help.

The `StratDate` & `EndDate` are separate KEYS under  (LIST VALUES) `OfferDateRange` but not sure how to define that in Java class.

You can check the JSON data through http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/, I am not able to paste a picture of it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class offers
    {
      private ArrayList<PkgData> pkg;

      class PkgData
      {
        Info Info;
        offerDateRange offerDateRange;


        class Info
        {
          int Id;

        }

        class offerDateRange
        {
          String StartDate;

          String EndDate;

        }

        public int getId() {
          return Info.Id;
        }

        public String getStartDate() {
          if (offerDateRange != null && offerDateRange.StartDate != null)
            return offerDateRange.StartDate;
          return "";
        }
   }

      public ArrayList<PkgData> getpkg() {
    return pkg;
  }

}


JSON:

{  
   "offerInfo":{  
      "siteID":"1",
      "language":"en_US",
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   "offers":{  
      "pkg":[  
         {  
            "offerDateRange":{  
               "StartDate":[  
                  2015,
                  11,
                  8
               ],
               "EndDate":[  
                  2015,
                  11,
                  14
               ]
            },
            "Info":{  
               "Id":"111"
            },
            "PricingInfo":{  
               "BaseRate":1932.6
            },
            "flt_Info":{  
               "Carrier":"AA"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

if start date and end date are two different variables .you can not get in one variable . 
append both date strings with comma .

```
   String date = startDate + "," + endDate ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Offers
{
    List<PkgData> pkg;
}
classs PkgData
{
    OfferDateRange offerDateRange;
    Info Info;
    PricingInfo PricingInfo ;
    Flt_Info Flt_Info;  
}
class OfferDateRange
{
    List<String> StartDate;
    List<String> EndDate;
}
```

Instead of this complex thing, try this http://www.json.org/java/.

Happy coding..!!

Comment: I am still unable to get it working with your code,it still not able to parse date fields

Comment: I think we need to handle startdate and enddate differently ..Please check the sample JSON in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/